# Why kafka consumer skiping some of the message while consuming from kafka topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot application which consume messages from kafka topic.
I have one topic called saurav-topic which have 4 partitions.
Currently this topic have around 300 000 messages.
Once consumer application started, it start consuming messages but some of the messages are skipping.
My question here why its skipping some of the messages while consuming.

KafkaConsumer.java:

```java
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
       
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.name}")
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> message) {
        System.out.println("Consumed message: " + message);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=ip-adr:9094
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id= group-id-dev-02
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset= earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records= 10
kafka.topic.name=saurav-topic
```

I have checked that the topic contains those messages which are skip while consuming.
Any ideas as to why this doesn't consume all messages from a kafka topic?

Example: i have 10 messages(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) in kafka queue , once start my spring boot application then kafka consumer reading some of messages like(1,2,3,6,8,10) that means 4,5,7,9 messages are skipped. why its happening any thing missing ?

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood

Comment: Clarify what you mean "skip". Please show output from message offsets. When your app starts, it does not always start at the beginning of the topic, and Kafka can delete data from the beginning topic after some time. It is also unclear if your topic is compacted.

Comment: Example: i have 10 messages(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) in kafka queue , once start my spring boot application then kafka consumer reading some of messages like(1,2,3,6,8,10) that means 4,5,7,9 messages are skipped. why its happening any thing missing ?

Comment: are these 10 messages in same partition?do you only have one consumer instance?